# CSS: Firefox and Chrome displaying differently

Tags: html, css, position, stylesheet, display

Not sure why simple

```
top: 218px;
```

would display differently for the 2 browsers.
I've reset the css stylings as well. Here's what I'm trying to do

```
<div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12 title">
          <h1 class = "welcome">Welcome</h1>
          <h4 class = "to">to</h4>
          <h1 class = "cda">XXXXX</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here's my reset:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

and here's my css styling:

```
.languages{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  top: 218px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the class `.languages` used within your **HTML**?

Comment: `top` doesn't work if you don't use any `position` like `position:absolute;`

Comment: And how do you know that the elements with class "languages" are displayed in different locations? They are invisible after all.